# How can i run a function after the program being on 12hrs in a row?

Tags: c#

How can i run a function on my program after the program was on for 12 hrs straight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timer:

```
        var timespan = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timespan.TotalMilliseconds);
        timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
        {
            // runs code here after 12 hours.
        };
        timer.Start();
```

Comment: Hey, thats great but is there a way i can print it onto a label? Like updating wise.

Comment: @user1233208 Do you mean update the UI from the timer background thread? If that is the case, then you need to marshal your UI code back onto the UI thread. It depends on what platform this is. e.g. Windows Forms something like this: `label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = "12 hours have elapsed"));`

Comment: @Tyson Ok. And.. for some reason the function where you told me to put it doesnt work.. would there be a reason to this? Heres my code :
http://pastebin.com/K9yaRd7P

Comment: @user1233208 Same reason as explained in my comment above about the labels. ShowDialog() is a UI call, all UI actions must be initiated from the UI thread, and the Timer thread is not the UI thread.

Comment: How would i do that? I cant seem to find any tuts

Comment: @user1233208 I already showed you with code in the comment above! If your not using win forms, but WPF, or something else, then I'm sure a google for "WPF marshal code to UI thread" or something similar will have 1000's of results, its a pretty common question. Actually I'm sure there are 1000's of questions right here on SO on this subject.

Comment: Even for non ui things? Yeah just the whole function doesn't work.

Comment: Just looked again - it could also be that your not keeping a reference to the timer. As soon as execution leaves your `Vote` method, the timer goes out of scope and will be garbage collected at some point. Try declaring the timer as a field variable of the class, or storing it in some other suitably long lived object.